# How does the .NET runtime move memory?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, runtime

It's a well known fact that the .NET garbage collector doesn't just 'delete' the objects on the heap, but also fights memory fragmentation using memory compaction. From what I understand, basically memory is copied to a new place, and the old place is at some point deleted.

My question is: how does this work?

What I'm mostly curious about is the fact that the GC runs in a separate thread, which means that the object we're working on can be moved by the GC *while we're executing our code*.

**Technical details of the question**

To illustrate, let me explain my question in more detail:

```
class Program
{
    private int foo;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tmp = new Program(); // make an object
        if (args.Length == 2)    // depend the outcome on a runtime check
        {
            tmp.foo = 12;        // set value ***
        }
        Console.WriteLine(tmp.foo);
    }
}
```

In this small example, we create an object and set a simple variable on an object. The point '***' is all that matters for the question: if the address of 'tmp' moves, 'foo' will reference something incorrect and everything will break.

The garbage collector runs in a separate thread. So as far as I know, 'tmp' can be moved during this instruction and 'foo' can end up with the incorrect value. But somehow, magic happens and it doesn't.

As for the disassembler, I noticed that the compiled program really takes the address of 'foo' and moves in the value '12:

```
000000ae 48 8B 85 10 01 00 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+00000110h] 
000000b5 C7 40 08 0C 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [rax+8],0Ch
```

I more or less expected to see an indirect pointer here, which can be updated- but apparently the GC works smarter than that.

Further, I don't see any thread synchronization that checks if the object has been moved. So how does the GC update the state in the executing thread?

So, how does this work? And if the GC doesn't move these objects, what is the 'rule' that defines wether or not to move the objects?

Comment: Note that old versions of .NET used a "stop-the-world" GC, so managed threads where stopped, GC was done, managed threads where resumed.

Comment: Are you aware that the GC only resumes the data when your instance of `Program` is out of scope? So as long as your app is running you´ll always have a correct value for `foo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET GC is (at least partially) a "stop-the-world" GC: it stops managed threads before doing its work, does its work, then restarts managed threads.

The "Workstation" GC can be *concurrent* (so partially not stop-the-world) but note at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee851764.aspx .

> When you are using workstation garbage collection with concurrent garbage collection, the reclaimed objects are not compacted, so the heap size can be the same or larger (fragmentation can make it appear to be larger).

Note that with all the GC, gen0 and gen1 are always stop-the-world. So they can move blocks of memory without problems. Only gen2 can be done in background by some GC with some configurations (this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee787088.aspx), the information is a little fragmented all around the page), so there is always a "the-world-is-stopped" moment where the memory that has been freed can be compacted.

Comment: Note that concurrent GC was effectively replaced with "background" GC starting with .Net 4. [Some details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @MatthewWatson And from 4.5 even the Server has a "background" GC. Still gen0 and gen1 are always "stop-the-world". Only gen2 works from another thread(s)

Comment: @xanatos That would mean that when 'stopping the world' you know exactly where the program counter is, what locals are in registers, which locals are where - etc. After GC you continue by restoring all that (etc) - even worse: you're doing all this on a different CPU than where you're currently running? I wouldn't even know how to get started if I wanted to implement that... How on earth do you do something like that?

Comment: @atlaste Think for a minute: the GC already knows where all the references to objects are: otherwise it couldn't do a collection :-) (if there is the last reference to object Foo in register EAX, the GC can't collect Foo, so clearly the GC must know that it has to look in EAX. Clearly when it "stops-the-world" it copies all the registers somewhere, so the GC doesn't really look in the registers, it looks in a copy of the registers that it does in memory when it stops-the-world). Then, if you know where the references are, modifying them becomes simple!

Comment: I believe the JIT actually outputs some metadata for the GC about which machine code ranges use which variables, so the GC doesn't have to look at any registers other than the instruction pointer (it wouldn't know if a value in a given register is a reference anyway).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yes, surely. But in general the registers have to be copied to the stack/to somewhere, because a processor can't read the registers of another processor. But as you said, there is some metadata in the code produced by the JITter that "writes" at each point of code which registers can contain a reference, and which positions of the stack can contain a reference (because a local variable could contain a reference that can be discarded at a certain point of a method because it is unused from that point onward)

Comment: @xanatos Well, you can just call `SuspendThread` and resume it later, right? It's basically a context switch. I'm just still unsure how to modify the values; it would make more sense to me if the GC simply doesn't modify addresses that are also in a register.

Comment: @atlaste It probably doesn't modify values that are in registers. When the thread is suspended, the registers are copied to memory, and probably go to the stack positions that would have if they weren't cached in a register. When the thread is resumed the opposite is done (and in the end in Assembly, every time you call a "method" the method has to save many registers to the stack to restore them back before returning, so this operation is "normal")

Comment: @xanatos Yes, what you're describing is basically a context switch. What I mean is that if f.ex. you have program ptr 0x10, and the GC knows that local X is used on offset 0x10, it would make sense to me if the memory at offset 0x10 is simply not compacted. After you restore the state then, everything will still work.

Comment: @atlaste Setting a cell of memory is setting a cell of memory. There is no difference if the cell is being used as "the stack" or as "the heap". If you have its address (and the GC *must* have its address, because local references are root for the GC collection), then "fixing" it to a new address is easy. The real complexity is tracking what are the "local" references that are "valid" in a certain point of the code (the metadata names by @LucasTrzesniewski). That must be as hard as I can imagine.

Comment: @xanatos Yes I understand that. What I'm struggling with is that that's pretty hard; I wouldn't know of any system call to get/modify that data (and I can imagine it also has issues with security). Also, Intel has different ways to store the processor state (XSAVEC / XSAVE / etc.)... Plain data that you 'own' as GC is much easier to modify. Personally I wouldn't know why you would go through the trouble, if it's only a handful of memory locations and you can still compact the rest.

Comment: @xanatos As for local references, while compiling, you can easily store a start/end offset for each local when they're used. Perhaps you can even exploit the SSA form or basic blocks during compilation. That's tricky, but seems do-able to me...

Comment: @atlaste One of the main reasons IL is a stack-based language is that the latter inherently implies so-called "sequence points", defined simply as points where the IL execution stack is empty. As far as I understand, when the JIT produces ASM from IL, it records the native code addresses corresponding to IL sequence points, which imply the native IP-value locations where it is safe to suspend for GC without having to worry about what's been picked up into registers.

Comment: @GlennSlayden It's stack-based, because both hardware and OS are designed and optimized for that. Think for example about native interop, calling conventions, exception unwinding, etc. However, I can clarify what happens: since I've asked this question, I've gone through the GC code in the CoreCLR repository. In a nutshell, the JIT tracks which native code address uses which registers as pointers. If no tracking info is available, suspend is unsafe (native, preamble, trailer) -> resume. The pointer registers are simply processed as root pointers (which is necessary because of reallocations).